# Auto-Layout on 4inch screen

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, autolayout

I am trying to get this view working with auto layout to accommodate both 3.5" screens and 4" screens. I am starting to feel like it is not possible only using auto-layout and IB.

Any insights? I have tried just about every combination of constraints I think would make sense (and many stabs in the dark) without luck.

Here is how it looks on a 3.5" screen (from IB but looks identical in the simulator)

[image]

Here is how it lays out on a 4" screen

[image]

Here are the constraints, let me know if there is a better way to show this information.

[image]

Comment: We'd probably need to see your autolayout mask/springs & struts diagram, but one thing you might want to consider is using a container view (a generic UIView into which you place all the controls you want to remain in constant relative position to one another), then turn off autosizing for the subviews and set autosizing on the container view only.

Comment: Updated to include screenshots of constraints, let me know if there is a better way to show this information. That is a good idea, I will try that out

Comment: Using your UIView container approach and switching back to springs/struts from auto layout worked. Not sure about this auto-layout feature yet, but would love to know if this is possible using it.

Comment: @ChrisWagner A side question. How do you create the textboxes as shown in your screenshots?

Comment: @Isuru it's just an image and I put borderless `UITextFields` on it

Answer (score 1):

The simplest (but not best) way would be to take each item on page and add the following constraints

1. "pin" width
2. "pin" height
3. Leading Space to superview
4. Top Space to superview
5. Remove all the other constraints.

This should lay out every staticly with all absolute values. It should work fine.... unless you rotate, but I'm not sure if you support landscape. If you do, replace step 4 with "Horizontal Center in Container" constraint.

Side note. Pink constraints are put in by Xcode because it is missing something it needs to position properly (you can't remove these). Blue ones are one you put in. Many times pink ones will vanish as you put in blue ones because you've giving it missing data Xcode needed to position the item.